# how i can change column values in a data frame in python

Tags: python-3.x

> How can I change values of age column if  age <=8 replace small age >8
>   and age <12   replace medium age >12 replace large.

```
import pandas as pd
data = pd.read_csv('abalone' )
data.columns= [  'Sex','Length','Diameter','Height','Whole_weight',
'Shucked_weight','Viscera_weight','shell_weight' ,'Rings']
data.head()
data["age"] = data["Rings"]+1.5
for row in data["age"]:
    if row < 12:
        data.loc[row,data["age"]]
    elif:
         data["age"][row]= "medium"
    else:
        data["age"][row]= "small"
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this can be done by replacing values first and then mapping them with the actually needed values :

```
data.loc[data['age'] <= 8, 'age'] = 1
data.loc[(data['age'] > 8) & (data['age'] < 12 ), 'age'] = 2
data.loc[data['age'] > 12, 'age'] = 3

data['age'] = data['age'].map({1: 'small', 2: 'medium', 3:'large'})
```

hope this helped